# How do I react to a user choosing "Don't Allow" when asking for permission to access Photos?

Tags: ios, delegates, photos, privacy

Basically, when they hit "Don't Allow", the imagePicker isn't showing the screen that gives the user the instructions to go into privacy settings and turn it on.

If I kill the app and go back, the privacy setting is there.  So I figured I probably need to manually do this when they touch "Don't Allow".

Is there a callback for when a user allows or doesn't allow access to their photo library? I can't find it in the docs.  At the very least I could dismiss the imageView.

Thanks!

Comment: Please read the notes when selecting tags.

Comment: @Remou can you tell me specifically what I did wrong?

Comment: It is a minor thing, the tag `access` is deprecated. You could end up with an `ms-access` answer :)

Comment: @JohnRiselvato That's not a duplicate in this case. The OP wants to know when the user actually selects "Don't Allow". The duplicate is for checking access ahead of time.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato Unfortunately no.  That questions is asking how to check if it is currently allowed.  I need to respond right when the user clicks "Don't Allow".  I imagine there is a callback already to the UIImagePickerViewController, because if you hit "Allow", your pictures (or the message that says you have no pictures) shows right away!  But if you hit "Don't Allow", the screen stays blank :(  I wonder if that's a bug with Apple, but either way I'd like to work around it. If I could execute some code when the user hits "Don't Allow" I think I can make it work.

^ I hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is the first time the user tries to access the photo library from your app then the user is asked whether it is allowed or not. If the user chooses "Don't Allow" then at that point there is no reason to show a message telling them to go to settings. They just made their decision.

As a rule you should use `ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus` so you can update your UI properly based on whatever choice the user made in the past.

But the 1st time it will be "not determined". There is no event that will tell you when the user actually makes their choice. And there is little need to know. If the user chooses "Don't Allow" they simply dismiss the image picker. If they choose "Allow" then they pick an image.

---

Answer:
The only option you have is to see if authorizationStatus returns ALAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined. If it does, use ALAssetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock: and wait for the result. If you get the failure block check the authorizationStatus again. If it is now ALAuthorizationStatusDenied then you know the user tapped "Don't Allow".

Comment: We actually do want to do something when the user says "Don't Allow".  Also, this doesn't explain why the UIImagePickerViewController doesn't show the text that tells the user he/she has said no.  (It shows if I close the image picker and go back... but not when they click "Don't Allow")

Comment: What do you want to do when the user taps "Don't Allow"? And no one but Apple can explain why the image picker shows nothing immediately after the user chooses "Don't Allow". Sounds like a bug. Report it to them.

Comment: For one, dismiss the imageviewpicker.  Secondly, for our user to get to that screen, they were very much trying to 'choose photo' (They took 2 actions towards that already).  Chances are good the "Don't Allow" was an accident, and we still want to redirect them to the page we would direct them to if they were denied / restricted. (That is handled now with ALAssetsLibrary. I really just need the "Don't Allow" action to trigger the same thing)

Comment: The only option you have is to see if `authorizationStatus` returns `ALAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`. If it does, use `ALAssetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:` and wait for the result. If you get the failure block check the `authorizationStatus` again. If it is now `ALAuthorizationStatusDenied` then you know the user tapped "Don't Allow".

Comment: Ah, that failureBlock might have been the thing I was looking for! I'll let you know if that worked.

Comment: enumerateGroupsWithTypes was the solution! Thanks a bunch.  It triggers the 'do you want to grant access' alert, and I can handle failure.  Thanks so much.