# How to dismiss imagePicker when user don't allow access in iOS

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am checking camera and photo permission on my App when user select or capture any image.
I am using this code.

```
-(void)choosePhotoFromExistingImages
 {   
    ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];
    if (status == ALAuthorizationStatusDenied  || status == ALAuthorizationStatusRestricted) {
        [APPDELEGATE showAlertViewForPhotos];
        //show alert for asking the user to give permission    
    }
    else{
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
        {
            UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
            controller.allowsEditing = YES;
            controller.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil] ;
            controller.delegate = self;
            [self presentViewController: controller animated: YES completion: nil];
        }
    }   
}
```

The code is working fine but when user first time choose Don't allow photo library it display a black screen like this same thing happening in camera.
What i need is that when user press on don't allow  i can check that user has cancel the permission so i can dismiss imagepicker  or camera .[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus` to check it

[How do I react to a user choosing "Don't Allow" when asking for permission to access Photos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942997/how-do-i-react-to-a-user-choosing-dont-allow-when-asking-for-permission-to-ac)

Comment: Yes for checking authorization i am using that only but what if user select don't allow first time then my image picker or camera still there, I just want to dismiss that first time

Comment: "The only option you have is to see if authorizationStatus returns ALAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined. If it does, use ALAssetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock: and wait for the result. If you get the failure block check the authorizationStatus again. If it is now ALAuthorizationStatusDenied then you know the user tapped "Don't Allow"."

Comment: I'm not sure. You can try it to know :)